# jQuery Toggle some problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create toggle without using toggle. When I pressed the button it should change the color to blue if press the button again it should change the color black again in some cases it is not working. (sorry for my poor english knowledge) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Caq/)

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class='button'>Click me</div>
</div>

.main {
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    background:black;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.button {
    padding: 10px 12px;
    background:#999;
    width:90px;
    margin: 110px auto;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}


var content = $('.main');
$('.button').on('click', function(){ 
    if(content == content.css({'background':'black'})){
        content.css({'background':'blue'})
    }else{
        content.css({'background-color':'black'})
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/5MNHD/)**

```
   var content = $('.main');
    $('.button').on('click', function(){ 
        if(content.hasClass("blue")){
            content.css({'background':'black'})
            content.removeClass("blue").addClass("black");
        }else{
            content.css({'background':'blue'})
            content.removeClass("black").addClass("blue");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var content = $('.main');

$('.button').on('click', function () {
    if (content.css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)")
        content.css({ 'background': 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' });
    else 
        content.css({ 'background': 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' });
})
```